# Android Activity, extend BaseActivity

Tags: android, templates, layout, android-activity, extends

What would be the correct way of implementing my idea? Should I use inflate?

Want to make aprox. 100 activities. All of them extending the same base-class (**BaseActivity**). What I want to accomplish is a **BaseActivity** that will show 3 View's (**LeftView**, **MainView**, **RightView**) in a LinearLayout (horizontal). This is not the problem. **MainView** is empty.

The problem arises when I want to design **MyActivity** (extends **BaseActivity**). My idea was that the R.layout designed in **MyActivity** ONLY was shown in MainView (part of **BaseActivity**).

Is this possible? and what would be the smartes/best way to implement this?

Kind regards, Ole

Comment: Dear god. I don't understand exactly what your problem is, but rethink your architecture before making 100 activities. You can likely achieve it with one activity/fragment pair and a good data structure.

Comment: Hehe the only reason for saying 100 activities, was to be sure nobody would suggest to rewrite the same xml-layout again and again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the way I choose to handle this, was by inflating the R.layout:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);
        return;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout da_layout_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.da_layout_main);
        View view_child = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.my_activity, null);
        da_layout_main.addView( view_child);
    }
}
```